# In which folder/file should a background gradient be defined in Android?

Tags: android, gradient

I am trying to add this gradient code to colors.xml but Eclipse keeps saying "Invalide start tag shape"

**projname/values/colors.xml** (what is currently here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient 
 android:type="radial" 
 android:gradientRadius="400"
 android:startColor="#88cce7"
 android:endColor="#075e81"/>
</shape>
<resources>
  <color name="bg_red">#FF0000</color>
  <color name="bg_white">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="bg_black">#000000</color>
  <color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
  <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

e.g. this is the gradient I am trying to emulate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMbNR.png

Comment: it should be in res/drawable folder

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), it belongs in the res/drawable folder.

res/drawable/**filename.xml**

Create that file and put your shape definition in there.